# How to assign record type to dependent picklist(from global picklist) in APEX

Tags: metadata-api, tooling-api

I have global picklist 'Country'

In my Address object i have picklist 'Country' which was created as a dependent picklist from globalpicklist.

Can we assign existing custom record type to this dependent picklist 'Country' of 'Address' object dynamically in code?

Comment: Why would you want to do that dynamically?

Comment: Because I have lot of global picklists and I want all my dependent picklists to be assigned to Record type, I would have lot of values i need to select and assign the record type manually for around 15 picklists where each one will have lot of values in entire application.